# Screen glitching in OS X Metal app? Error (IOAF code 1)?

Tags: macos, gpu, metal, visual-glitch, metalkit

I'm making an app on OS X Sierra using Metal.  Something I am doing is causing the screen to start glitching badly, flashing black in various places, which quickly escalates to the entire screen going black.

In XCode, if I use the GPU frame capture, the paused frame appears correct however -- it suddenly returns from the black abyss.  I don't see any errors or warnings in the GPU frame information.  However, I am relatively new to Metal and am not experienced with the frame debugger, so I may not know what to look for.

Usually there is nothing printed to the console, but occasionally I do get one of these:

> Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Internal Error (IOAF code 1)

The same app runs on iOS devices without this problem -- so far it only happens on OS X.  Does this sound familiar?  Any suggestions on what I should check?

I can post some code if it will be helpful, but right now I'm not sure what part of the program is the problem.

EDIT: In response to Noah Witherspoon -- it seems that the problem is caused by some kind of interaction between my scene drawing and the UI drawing.  If I display only my scene, which is composed of fat, fuzzy lines, then the problem does not occur.  It also does not occur if I display only the UI, which is orthographic projection, a bunch of rounded rectangles and some type.  The problem happens only when both are showing.  This is a lot of code, many buffers and a lot of commandBuffer usage, too much to put into a post.  But here is a little bit.

My lines are rendered with vertex buffers which are arrays of floats, four per vertex:

```
let dataSize = count * 4 * MemoryLayout<Float>.size
vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: points, length: dataSize, options: MTLResourceOptions())!
```

These are rendered like this:

```
renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self.vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(strokeNode.strokePipelineState)
renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangleStrip, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: Int(widthCountEdge.count)*2-4)

renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(strokeNode.capPipelineState)
renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 12)
```

Here's my main loop for drawing with the command Buffer.

```
if let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() {

    commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler { (commandBuffer) -> Void in
        self.strokeNode.bufferProvider.availableResourcesSemaphore.signal()
    }

    self.updateDynamicBufferState()
    self.updateGameState(timeInterval)

    let renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor

    renderPassDescriptor?.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
    renderPassDescriptor?.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
    renderPassDescriptor?.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store

    if let renderPassDescriptor = renderPassDescriptor, let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor) {

        strokeNode.subrender(renderEncoder, parentModelViewMatrix: viewMatrix, projectionMatrix: projectionMatrix, renderer:self)

        mainscreen.draw(renderEncoder);

        renderEncoder.endEncoding()

        if let drawable = view.currentDrawable {
            commandBuffer.present(drawable)
        }
    }

    commandBuffer.commit()
}
```

The line drawing happens in strokeNode.subrender, and then my UI drawing happens in mainscreen.draw.  The UI drawing has a lot of components - a lot to list here -- but I will try taking them out one by one and see if I can narrow it down.  If none of this looks problematic I'll edit and post some of that ...

Thanks!

Comment: Two areas of your code would be useful: how you’re setting up any buffers you’re using, and what you’re doing with your command encoders. The disparity between iOS and macOS suggests it’s something to do with buffer memory access, but it’s hard to guess without seeing more.

Comment: I posted some code -- but now I am wondering if the problem could be related to my use of setVertexBytes()?  I've been using that instead of SetVertexBuffer for all of my uniforms and smaller vertex lists, thinking it was better than using an MTLBuffer for something so small.  But rereading the docs, it says it is really for "one-time' use -- like not even once per frame, but once ever?  I could be over-using this function.

Comment: `setVertexBytes` is definitely fine to use per-frame—it’s meant for small chunks of data, like shader uniforms. The code you’ve posted so far looks fine at a glance; are your vertex / fragment shaders particularly complicated?

Comment: There's one shader that is a little complicated, but I doubt it is the problem.  I'll take that part out and see.  I also just totally refactored my color palette, which I suspected, and it didn't fix it.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Metal -- wondering if there is something fundamental I am missing?  It seems like the GPU is timing out -- are you supposed to break up your command buffers into small batches?  Or does the entire scene render typically go into one big command buffer per frame?  I have not seen any documentation regarding this so I assumed one command buffer per frame for the whole scene.  Is that incorrect?